# Django "This field is required." in Postman

Tags: python, django, serialization, postman

## serializers.py

class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
image = serializers.CharField(read_only=True) 
class Meta:
    model = Card
    fields = ('id', 'template', 'data', 'MD5', 'image_md5',
              'image', 'target_url', 'title', 'description',
              'created', 'updated', 'createdBy')
    read_only_fields = ['MD5', 'image_md5', 'image', 'createdBy']

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = self.context.get('request').user
    if not user.id:
        raise ValidationError("Login Required")
    validated_data['createdBy'] = user
    return super(CardSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    new_ins = Card(**validated_data)
    md5 = new_ins.gen_md5()
    lookup = Card.objects.filter(MD5=md5).first()
    if lookup:
        return lookup

    return super(CardSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

## postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxWEe.png)

Comment: can you share the models please?

Comment: could you please elaborate what you are looking for